# Is safety of Object as dictonary really really guaranteed by standard?

Tags: javascript, security

```
var x = Object.create(null);
x["hello"] = "world";
```

But can I allow unverified user input as keys? I want to use it as player name -> player object map. Player names will only be constrained by length of 32. I'm worried if there are special property keys that would allow players to gain control of the server.

EDIT: I'm not making web server. JavaScript will be ran server-side via SpiderMonkey embedded into the game server. If someone hijacks the JavaScript running there, they could ruin the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one word: no, just remember the [Google Docs `__proto__` fail](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/0hQWeOvCcHU)

You should use a `Hash`-like class, or at least access these keys prefixed:

```
var hash = {}, key = "something-evil", value = Math.PI;
hash["$" + key] = value;
console.log( hash["$" + key] == value );
```

Comment: `__proto__` comes from Object.prototype, at least on my Firefox. If I create an object with `null` prototype, it doesn't have `__proto__`.

Comment: Yes, but it is supported in webkit & opera too, and if you create objects with `Object.create(null)`, the `__proto__` setter still works, because its not comes from `Object.prototype`, instead it reflects the inner [[Prototype]] property - in Chrome and Opera.

You're right, FF is an exception here.

Answer (score 2):

**Property keys are always strings.** You'll never encounter a problem with any property name, except for maybe:

- [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty). For example in:

  ```
  var obj = {hasOwnProperty:'fail'};
  for (var i in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) ; // ...
  }
  ```

  which can be solved by using `Object.keys(obj).forEach( ... )` or:

  ```
  for (var i in obj) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) ; // ...
  }
  ```
- The only hazard is caused by how you deal with the object. The previous example is not an uncommon usage of `hasOwnProperty`, but it *can* be used to break your script, because you don't expect the key name `hasOwnProperty`. The same can apply to `.toString`, or any other property of the object which can be overriden by setting a new name.

Comment: Won't Object.create(null) create an object that doesn't even have hasOwnProperty?

Comment: @lamefun Yes, that's correct. Your code is safe, because you do *not expect* any pre-defined properties/methods. That, and "property keys are always strings" should be sufficient to sleep well ;)

Comment: Amazingly, I ran into a bug today caused by this in some old code. Properties were being added to an object based on user input, and there was a situation that could result in a `hasOwnProperty` property being added. And your suggestion is just what I did too, so +1!

Answer (score 0):

No, an object is basically a blank slate, there are no special keys. On top of that, even if somebody hacks your Javascript it is very unlikely that they will gain control of your server unless you are using *very* lax security policies (like putting the root password in your Javascript or something silly like that).

Comment: I want to use JavaScript server-side via embedding a JavaScript engine into the game server. Although I won't expose system functions to it, it's still undesirable that someone will ruin the game.

Comment: Ah, in that case it depends on what you are exposing to the embedded engine, and what software you're using for the embedded engine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control what will be sent to your web server. At all. Ever.

So, you need to put restrictions on what you server will do, in response to anything sent to it. Part of this is validating all user input, even if it's JSON representing a JavaScript object that was created by your code.